# Count the clicks from a single user // Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, count

I have an input field on the frontend. Is it possible to count the clicks on that field from a logged-in user and save it to the column in the backend? I wanna see, how much times this user clicked on the field.

I created a new column for the userpage.

```
function user_clicks_table( $column ) {
$column['user_clicks'] = 'Klicks / Heute';
return $column; 
} 
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'user_clicks_table' );
```

Comment: Do you want to count physical clicks or the amount of times the form was submitted? For the clicks, you would have to bind a Javascript/jQuery event and then possibly do an AJAX request that writes to the table. If you want to keep track of the form submit, you could do it within your form processing logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in php to handle saving clicks to the db, and make it avaible trough wp's wp_ajax action ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action) ).

Then its a matter of binding javascript to clicks and posting the data to the action :)